# Generate OAuth Token using R

Tags: r, api, oauth, token, generate

Novice - first time attempting to extract data via an API and using R.

I obtained a API Key and the Secret.

Converted to base64.

Now perplexed as to the next step where the instructions that I have state that I should "Enter the generated base64value in the header and request body and call the token URI as shown below;

[Code]
Authorization: Basic {base64value}
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
POST https://api.destination.com/oauth/token
grant_type=client_credentials
[/Code]

Any insight as to if R can be used to obtain the OAuth Token?

If so, what are the required packages that I need to install?

What are the specific steps?

Currently reading several books on R but thought that someone will be able to provide some insight.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `httr` package is a great place to start learning API's in R. If you haven't been lead there already I highly recommend taking the time to [check it out](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html).

```
library(httr)

base64_value <- your_generated_base64string

response <- 
  POST(url = "https://api.precisely.com/oauth/token",
       add_headers(Authorization = paste("Basic", base64_value))
       body = list(grant_type = "client_credentials"),
       encode = "form")

# we're hoping this is 200
response$status
```

Comment: Response [https://api.destination.com/oauth/token]
  Date: 2021-07-22 09:22
  Status: 401
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 94 B

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original documentation?

Comment: https://docs.precisely.com/docs/sftw/precisely-apis/main/en-us/webhelp/apis/index.html#Getting%20Started/getting_started.html

library(httr)

base64_value <-
123456899999=

response3 <-
  httr::POST (url = "https://api.precisely.com/oauth/token/",
             httr::add_headers(Authorization = paste("Basic", 123456899999=)),
             body = list(grant_type = "client_credentials"),
             encode = "form"
             )

Error in paste("Basic", 123456899999) : 
  argument is missing, with no default

Comment: You had two errors in your call. The first is that your url did not include the `https://` portion of the URL. The second is that your base64 string wasn't quoted. It was trying to evaluate or assign because of the `=` at the end. Edited the answer.

Comment: Any additional insight?

Comment: When I run the code you added as an answer, I get a 401 error. That's telling me that the server has received the POST request but the credentials are wrong either because `1234...` is an old token, is typed incorrectly, or is in the wrong format. If you run `httr::content(response14, "text")` you get a more detailed description that tells you you have invalid or missing client credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not work.  A status code of 401 is the result.

After attempting this numerous times, maybe I need to once again regenerate another key and secret.  Then, obtain another base64 value.  Then, try again.  Other options include trying Rcurl or even trying Python.

I assume that the server eventually locks out a base64value after so many unsuccessful attempts.

Appreciate the time/insight.

Any additional insight is appreciated.

```
library(httr)

base64_value <-
  "123456789="
  

response14 <-
  httr::POST (url = "https://api.precisely.com/oauth/token",
             httr::add_headers(Authorization = paste("Basic", base64_value)),
             body = list(grant_type = "client_credentials"),
             encode = "form"
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest iteration.

Error received is regarding timeout.

```
library(httr)

base64_value <-
  "123456789="
  

response14 <-
  httr::POST (url = "https://api.precisely.com/oauth/token",
             httr::add_headers(Authorization = paste("Basic", "123456789=")),
             body = list(grant_type = "client_credentials"),
             encode = "form"
             )
```

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
Timeout was reached: [api.precisely.com] Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds